# dotnet core crossplatform (Windows & CentOS) timezone conversion error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core, centos7, timezone-offset

I have a dotnet core asp.net mvc app that needs to do timezone conversions between UTC, Central Time Zone and Singapore Standard Time.  I have this working in my windows development environment using the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` method to set a timezone instance and passing that timezone instance into `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` to get the time for the desired timezone.  However, when I deploy the web app to CentOS7 I get the error:

> "Could not find file '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Central Standard Time'."

---

What do I need to do to get this to work on both platforms?

```
   public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_timeZoneInstance == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _timeZoneInstance = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone);
                }
                catch
                {
                    TimeZone = "Central Standard Time";
                    _timeZoneInstance = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone);
                }
            }
            return _timeZoneInstance;
        }
        private set { _timeZoneInstance = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? GetUserTime(DateTime? utcTime = null)
    {

        if (utcTime == null)
            return utcTime;

        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcTime.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc), TimeZoneInfo.Utc, TimeZoneInstance);
    }

    public DateTime? GetUtcTime(DateTime? localTime)
    {
        if (localTime == null)
            return localTime;



        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localTime.Value, TimeZoneInstance, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core on Windows uses [Windows time zone IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx) while .NET Core on *nix uses IANA time zones.

The easiest approach of cross-platform time zones is using IANA IDs with [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/). With NodaTime, you can retrieve a time zone with this:

```
NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/Chicago");
```

A list of time zone IDs is available at:

```
NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.Ids
```

You do need to add an external dependency and use `NodaTime.DateTimeZone` instead of `TimeZoneInfo`. However, it is more cross-platform friendly than `TimeZoneInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Untill Microsoft provide a global solution you can use this package:
https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter